# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'online_examination_system.studentapp_courses' doesn't exist")

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, error-handling

I tried makemigrations, migrate, and even many methods stated in stack overflow but nothing is happening. Please tell me the reason why this happens and how can i solve it?

Comment: Can you show your `models.py`?

Comment: Can you show your Code ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you :-

Delete all the migrations in your app except init.py file. AND then again type `python manage.py make makemigrations` and type `python manage.py migrate`